# How to send an audio file as attachment in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry

How to send an audio file as attachment in BlackBerry SDK 6?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the audiofile into a bytearray and then use the following method

```
public synchronized boolean sendMail(final byte []data,
                    final boolean licensed) 
            {    
            Folder[] folders = store.list(4);
            Folder sentfolder = folders[0];
            // create a new message and store it in the sent folder
            msg = new Message(sentfolder);
            multipart = new Multipart();
            textPart = new TextBodyPart(multipart,"Audio");
            Address recipients[] = new Address[1];
            try {

                    recipients[0] = new Address(address, "XYZ");
                    msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, recipients);
                    msg.setSubject("Audio"); 
                    try {
                            Thread thread = new Thread("Send mail") {
                                    public void run() {
                                            emailSenderIsBusy = true;
                                            try {


                                                        attach = new SupportedAttachmentPart(
                                                                    multipart, "application/octet-stream",
                                                                    "title",data);                                                      


                                                    multipart.addBodyPart(textPart);
                                                    multipart.addBodyPart(attach);
                                                    msg.setContent(multipart);
                                                    Transport.send(msg); 
                                            }
                                            catch(SendFailedException e)
                                            {

                                            } 
                                            catch (final MessagingException e) { 


                                            } 
                                            catch (final Exception e) { 

                                            }

                                    }           
                            };
                            thread.start(); 
                            return true;
                    } 
                    catch (final Exception e) 
                    { 

                    }
            }catch (final Exception e) {

            }

            return false;
    }
```

Comment: how to get bytes from an audio file ?

Comment: @Signare, you can see my answer to [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11168477/119114).  It's reading a PDF file into a `byte[]`, but it should be the same for any binary data file.